# When a public company is selling new shares at the market, will the public know it?

Tags: stocks, shares, dilution

I have asked a question [What shares are actually being sold in “ATM” format release?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/95980/what-shares-are-actually-being-sold-in-atm-format-release/95983#95983) - From the answer, I understand that a company could be able to sell new shares to gain more money for its operation.

But when will the public be notified?

Let's still take the $HMNY company for instance. It's been jumping lower for days. Does that mean the company has already (secretly) selling new shares ATM? Is that legal? How does the ATM offering actually work?

Thanks,

Comment: In principle, issuing and selling new shares shouldn't affect the price of the existing shares. It dilutes the ownership of the existing shares, but the new money increases the value of the company by the same amount, so the net effect should be zero.

Comment: For traditional secondaries, share price sometimes reacts, depending on the perception of the terms of the secondary.

Comment: 7/24/18: Helios and Matheson Analytics Inc. announces 1-for-250 reverse stock split.  RUT ROH...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when will the public be notified?

"Never".

A company can only create shares like that with the permission of the shareholders and under a plan the board has approoved. Those information is public when made.

From then on, the management will follow this and just sell on the market as it sees fit.

Comment: so the company can only sell new shares after telling everyone? right？

Comment: Well, the shareholder decsiions are public. Shareholders meet once per year. But if the shareholders agree that the board/management can sell another 1 million shares for a minimum price X, then this decision allows management to sell them when they want.

Comment: @AGamePlayer For new shares, that is correct, but note that “telling everyone” just means putting it in the minutes of the AGM. But if the company holds existing shares in its treasury, it can sell them without getting anyone’s permission or telling anyone.

Comment: @MikeScott thanks for the updates, would you please tell me what is `AGM`?

Comment: @MikeScott And one more question, you said `it can sell them without getting anyone’s permission`, what is `it`? I don't think a company can sell, only shareholders can sell. a company can only offer new shares to get money. that is also what I've told in the other question that I mentioned at my question.

Comment: Annual General Meeting. Might be called a shareholders’ meeting so something similar in the US.

Comment: @AGamePlayer A company that holds its own shares in its treasury is a shareholder like any other, and can sell those shares, just as if they were shares in a different company. https://www.everymanlegal.co.uk/wpcms/wp-content/uploads/Fact-Sheet-Treasury-Shares.pdf

Comment: @MikeScott How can a company itself own shares? Who makes the decision on behalf of the shares then? Or, are those shares just some "coin in the pool that the management team can decide how to use them, like to give to good employers or to sell for company money"?

Comment: @AGamePlayer If you want to know all about treasury shares, that’s a new question, and should be asked as such.

Comment: @MikeScott oh, I will search it by Google. not a native speaker so I misunderstand it. Thanks so much for your patience. :)

Comment: "How can a company itself own shares?" - buy order on exchange connected to a portfolio account. What is the question here? "Who makes the decision on behalf of the shares then? " Noone. Shares make no decisions. Share owners do. Now guess who is authorized to make decisions for a company? What is the qeustion here?

Comment: Like traditional secondary offerings, At-The-Market Equity offerings are announced to the public. You can Google for names of  companies that have offered them.  I don't think  it should be characterized as secretly selling new shares because the ATM offering has authorized the future sale of shares.  There would be no way to know if such share sales were causing share price to drop unless you could get hold of the company filings.

Comment: @BobBaerker Did you mean that the company might have already sold the new shares while their SEC-filings are yet to come?

Comment: No, I did not mean/say that.  The company announces an At-The-Market Equity offering and it  includes language spelling out the company *MAY*   issue and sell up to an aggregate of $ (fill in the number) million of its common stock.  Google it for some examples.

Comment: @BobBaerker Sorry I tried Google but not sure what's the best keywords. Anyway, did you mean that the company who said "we're gonna A-T-M offering" might already be selling new shares (and we need to wait for the next 8-k to know the details), right?

Comment: @AGamePlayer No. The shareholders decide the company MAY sell ATM a number of shares up to X. The exactl conditions and limitations are part of that decisions. You overthink and underread the issue.

Comment: @TomTom then what about the decision is already made and the X number of shares is also decided. In the real selling status, will the company have to tell everyone before or the company can just ahead and sell and nobody knows when the X shares is completely sold?

Comment: Well, you know, this is a Q&A site. It is not a "we give you every legal detail regardless how small it is". Want to know all the details? PAY SOMEONE - or read the relevant regulations, which, btw., are available to the public. Your question was anderes - WAY more detailed than this site normally is used for.

Comment: @AGamePlayer  - Note the conditional words in the ATM announcement by NW last year:  "NorthWestern Corporation (NWE) announced today that it has established an "at-the-market" equity offering program through which it MAY sell up to an aggregate of $100 million of its common stock. Under the program, the Company MAY offer and sell shares of its common stock OVER A PERIOD OF TIME and from time  to time through BofA Merrill Lynch and J.P. Morgan, as sales agents. "MAY means in the future after the announcement.

Comment: @BobBaerker Does that mean that every trade ever been made is possible an A-T-M trade? Actually, for my case, the $HMNY price dropped fast and sometimes huge amount of shares got sold in less than a minute. I would like to know whether it's possible to be the A-T-M trade. Thanks very much for your patience to help out.

Comment: @AGamePlayer - HMNY's average volume is 15M shares so it's not possible that "every trade ever been made is possible an A-T-M trade."  This is a battered stock.  There's no boogeyman here. The ATM offering is not the cause of HMNY's downfall.

Comment: @BobBaerker but you can’t conclude that the atm offering hasn’t started at all, right?

Comment: And you can't conclude that it has started - unless filings indicate otherwise.